# PHP on how to auto combine values in array to given sum

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, sum

I would like to sum up value(s) in the array to match the nearest answer to given sum number.

- Following scenario/example is provided 1-5 items, sum up each values to 200 (minimum).
- If combination of 2 values are 200, then return the keys.
- Combination of items up to 3 items only. Given 4 items, if combination of 2 items are 205, while other combinations are 210, pick up the first 2 combinations.

I have read and study from many PHP resources but there's none I can easily and fully understand how to solve my problems for my PHP application.

Given 2 tables as following, my coding only work on either if I change the logical operator.

How to make the coding works for both. Kindly point out mistake form my coding and suggest a solution for me.

Table A:

```
Item | Name       | Price
----- ------------ --------
1    | Adidas     | 190.00
2    | Nike Run   | 170.00
3    | Puma       | 110.00
4    | Nike Women |  30.00
```

The working code for above table A:

```
$values = [
    1=>320;
    2=>50;
    3=>120;
    4=>10;
    5=>30;
];
echo implode(',', getKeys($values,200));

function getKeys($array, $min, $keys=array())
{   
    // Select the smallest value that less than given value.
    if(empty($keys)){
        $keep[] = array(0,0);
        foreach($arrays as $key=>$value){
            $keep[1] = isset($keep[1]) ? $keep[1] : null;
            if($value <= $min && $value > $keep[1] ){
                $keep[0]=$key;
                $keep[1]=$value;
                break 1;
            }else{
                //$keep[0]=$key;
                $keep[1]=$value;
            }   
        }
        $keys[] = $keep[0];
    }

    $total = 0;
    foreach($keys as $key){
        if(!empty($arrays)){
            $total += $arrays[$key];
        }
    }

    if($total >= $min){
        $keep[] = array(0,0);               
        $keep[1] = $total;

        foreach($arrays as $key=>$value){
            if($value >= $min && $value < $keep[1] && !in_array($key, $keys)){
                $keep[0]=$key;
                $keep[1]=$value;
                break 1;
            }
        }

        if($total <= $keep[1]){
            if(count($keys) > 3){
                //Restricted only 3 keys to be return, remove smallest value
                $keep[] = array(0,0);       

                foreach($arrays as $key=>$value){
                    $keep[1] = isset($keep[1]) ? $keep[1] : null;
                    if($value <= $min && $value < $keep[1]){
                        $keep[0]=$key;
                        $keep[1]=$value;
                        break 1;
                    }else{
                        $keep[0]=$key;
                        $keep[1]=$value;
                    }   
                }
                for($z = 0; $z < count($keys); $z++){
                    if($keys[$z] == $keep[0]){
                        unset($keys[$z]);
                    }
                }
                return $this->getCamp1($array, $min, $keys);
            }else{
                sort($keys);
                return $keys;
            }
        }else{
            unset($keys);
            $keys[] = $keep[0];
            return $this->getKeys($array, $min, $keys);
        }
    }else{
        // Select the next value that can exceed min
        if(!empty($keys)){
            $next = NULL;
            $arrays = array_keys($array);               
            foreach($arrays as $key=>$value){   
                if($value < $min && ($value + $total) >= $min && !in_array($key,$keys)){
                    $next=$key;
                    break 1;
                }
            }
        }

        if(empty($next)){
            // Pick the next biggest value that less than minimum value ($200)
            $keep[] = array(0,0);               
            $counterCamp = count($array);

            foreach($arrays as $key=>$value){
                $keep[1] = $min; 
                if($value < $min && $value < $keep[1]  && !in_array($key, $keys)){
                    $keep[0]=$key;
                    $keep[1]=$value;
                    break 2;
                }else{
                    $keep[1]=$value;
                }   
                $counterCamp--;
            }                       

            //  Reselect value more than 200            
            if($counterCamp == 0){
                foreach($arrays as $key=>$value){
                    if($value > $min && $value < $keep[1] && !in_array($key, $keys)){
                        $keep[0]=$key;
                        $keep[1]=$value;    
                        unset($keys);
                        break 2;
                    }else{
                        $keep[0]=$key;
                        $keep[1]=$value;
                        unset($keys);
                        break 2;            
                    }
                }
            }                       
            $keys[] = $keep[0];
            return $this->getKeys($array, $min, $keys);
        }else{
            $keys[] = $next;
            return $this->getKeys($array, $min, $keys);
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Result:

```
Item | Name       | Price
----- ------------ --------
2    | Nike Run   | 170.00
4    | Nike Women |  30.00
```

Following table B is not working unless update following coding

Table B:

```
Item | Name       | Price
----- ------------ --------
1    | Adidas     |  90.00
2    | Nike Run   | 180.00
3    | Puma       |  15.00
4    | Nike Women |  25.00
```

The working code for above table B:

```
    // Select the smallest value that less than given value.
    if(empty($keys)){
        $keep[] = array(0,0);
        foreach($arrays as $key=>$value){
            $keep[1] = isset($keep[1]) ? $keep[1] : null;
            if($value <= $min && $value < $keep[1] ){
                $keep[0]=$key;
                $keep[1]=$value;
                break 1;
            }else{
                //$keep[0]=$key;
                $keep[1]=$value;
            }   
        }
        $keys[] = $keep[0];
    }
```

Desired Result:

```
Item | Name       | Price
----- ------------ --------
2    | Nike Run   | 180.00
4    | Nike Women |  25.00
```